# What is the city equivalent of 'hillbilly hell"?

Tags: phrase-requests, american-english, antonyms, pejorative-language

As you may have already known, and for those of you who don't know, hillbilly hell is a term used to mock the countryside in the USA, with all of its perceived flaws (insular, racist, decaying ...). Is there a term with a similar connotation being used to describe cities, or urban places in general? The term should only be used to deride the general metropolis landscape (think LA or NY), and should not be focusing on any particular city.

Comment: For your consideration: an [Ngram of 'urban hellhole' versus 'hillbilly hell'](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=urban+hellscape%2Curban+hellhole%2Chillbilly+hell&year_start=1940&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) for the period 1940–2019. Evidently you don't have to live in the countryside to have your environment equated with a place of damnation.

Comment: What connotations do you want? There are lots of negative terms for cities, ranging from those emphasising business, pollution, and noise to denigrating cities for racist or homophobic reasons. And are we talking New York-size cities or cities of 50,000 people?

Comment: A quest for racist terms needs our help?

Comment: City without pity?

Comment: I've never heard the phrase "hillbilly hell". But here's a twist: How do you make a hillbilly holler?

Comment: No takers?  Well, you get you a H, and then a O, and then a L, and then a other L, and a other O, and then a W, and put it all together, H-O-L-L-O-W, wa-la.

Comment: @StuartF I'm looking for some thing that denigrates the hustling and bustling of the city lifestyle. And by city, I mean a city at the metropolis level, think NY, Tokyo and the like.

Comment: Okay, now edit your question to include that, and it will get sent to the reopen que. You may also want to specify if the term must play off stereotypes of it's residents, or if it can just deride the cityscape. *Asphalt jungle* and *Gotham* are two examples of the latter.

Comment: Sven Yargs has give a valid answer.

Comment: The phrase *hillbilly hell*, considered on its own, is capable of carrying two opposed meanings: it can mean something so **infused with the hillbilly culture** that non-hillbillies experience it as hell, but it could alternatively mean something so devoid of the hillbilly culture that **hillbillies experience it as hell**.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it precisely fits your needs, but "urban decay" and "urban blight" are common terms that refer to the problems that often afflict large cities. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urban_decay):

> Urban decay (also known as urban rot, urban death or urban blight) is the sociological process by which a previously functioning city, or part of a city, falls into disrepair and decrepitude. There is no single process that leads to urban decay

Comment: Urban decay/ Urban blight is a city phenomenon, but not used to denigrate city themselves. I want a term that denigrates cities that put an emphasis on the bustling & hustling thereof, not just a denomination to describe a city phenomenon.